# Adicionar Classe em atributo span de acordo com a url

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu tenho um atributo span e preciso inserir uma classe para forçar a ocultá-lo se ele estiver dentro de uma URL, eu quero fazê-lo totalmente em javascript.

Código que estou fazendo

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
var classe = document.querySelector('span.price');
classe.forEach(function(classe){
  if(window.location.href == "https://www.myurl.com.br/product") {
classe.classList.add('force-hide');
  }});
});
```

```css
.force-hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-details"> 
<strong class="product name product-item-name"> 
<a class="product-item-link" href="https://www.myurl.com.br/product"> Product </a> 
</strong>
<div class="price-box price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product-id="2293" data-price-box="product-id-2293">
<span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee"> 
<span id="product-price-2293" data-price-amount="13.9" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
<span class="price">R$13,90</span>
</span> 
</span> 
</div></div>
```

Quero ter certeza de que, se estiver no URL indicado, adiciona uma classe force-hide no atributo span.

Comment: Mas seu script funciona já meu caro. Qual é o problema ai? Aqui testando localmente o span com o preço sumiu direitinho...

Comment: @hugocsl entendo,são vários desse em minha página será necessário criar um foreach.Para adicionar corretamente em todos.

Comment: @hucsl atualizei com foreach

Comment: A ideia é bem essa, mas será que é bom manter essa funcionalidade no front-end? As informações continuarão ali, só não é mostrada